# Crash in BOXKeychainItemWrapper.m

Tags: box-api, box

App crashes suddenly once in a while in method
**resetKeychainItem**
at line 210:

```
NSAssert( junk == noErr || junk == errSecItemNotFound, @"Problem deleting current dictionary." );
```

Is there any way to avoid this crash/Any update on this issue?

Method:

```
- (void)resetKeychainItem
{
   @synchronized(self) {
      OSStatus junk = noErr;
      if (self.keychainItemData != nil)
      {
        NSMutableDictionary *tempDictionary = [self dictionaryToSecItemFormat:self.keychainItemData];
        junk = SecItemDelete((CFDictionaryRef)tempDictionary);

        NSAssert( junk == noErr || junk == errSecItemNotFound, @"Problem deleting current dictionary." );
        // Default data for keychain item.
        self.keychainItemData = [self defaultKeychainItemDataDictionaryWithIdentifier:self.identifier
                                                                          accessGroup:self.accessGroup];
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll respond through the issue you submitted in GitHub:
https://github.com/box/box-ios-sdk/issues/117